# How are C structs with arrays returned?

Tags: c, struct, assignment-operator

Suppose we have:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t someVal;
} Entry

typedef struct {
    Entry grid[3][3];
} Matrix

//Make a 3x3 matrix of all 0s
Matrix emptyMatrix(void) {
    Entry zero = {.value = 0}
    Matrix matrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            //Shallow copy empty struct
            matrix.grid[i][j] = zero;
        }
    return matrix;
}

Matrix myMatrix = emptyMatrix();
```

I understand that in C we're [allowed to return a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653072/return-a-struct-from-a-function-in-c) from a function so this works and I've tested it. However, it's unclear to me HOW the assignment works.

Does the compiler allocate the memory for `myMatrix` then copy each `Entry` element of the array in the `Matrix` struct returned by `emptyMatrix()`?

I guess it would also be helpful to know the memory map of `Matrix` - I assumed that since `grid` is an array that `Matrix`'s memory would contain pointers. However, it apparently stores the [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798894/memory-layout-of-c-struct-with-arrays). If this is the case, my guess for how the assignment works makes much more sense to me.

Edit: It seems like people are answering the question incompletely. I want to know whether my guess of how the assignment works is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Each instance of `Matrix` will contain a 3x3 *array* of `Entry`.  When you assign one instance of `Matrix` to another, the contents of the source matrix will be copied to the destination matrix.

Arrays are not pointers.  Array *expressions* will "decay" to pointers if the expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is not a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration.

For example, if you had a function call like

```
printMatrix( myMatrix.grid );
```

the *expression* `myMatrix.grid` has type "3-element array of 3-element array of `Entry`"; since it's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, it "decays" to an expression of type "pointer to 3-element array of `Entry`" (`Entry (*)[3]`) and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of `grid` (which will also be the address of the whole `Matrix` instance).

Answer (score 1):

The ABI for each environment defines how structures are passed and returned by value. A common choice is this:

- small structures, up to the size of 2 or 4 registers are returned in registers.
- for larger objects, the caller allocates space on its stack frame for the return value and passes a pointer to the function.  When returning, the function copies whatever object is being returned into the space to which it received a pointer for the return value. That's it.  This simple method allows for recursive calls.
- the optimizer tries to minimize the amount of copying, especially if it can expand the function inline or if the returned value is stored into an object, as opposed to discarded or passed by value to another function.

It does not matter if the structure has one or more member arrays.  The same method applies to unions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers bound to arrays may be interpreted as pointers, but that doesn't mean that the array variables are pointers.

The storage for the array is part of the memory layout of the struct itself. The same way as arrays declared on the stack are on the stack itself.

You can test this by yourself by checking `sizeof(Matrix)`.

So in short:

> Does the compiler allocate the memory for myMatrix then copy each Entry element of the array in the Matrix struct returned by emptyMatrix()?

Yes

Comment: Can you explain "Identifiers bound to arrays" part more?

Answer (score 0):

`Matrix` is a data type `struct struct {Entry grid[3][3];}`. For every object of the type `Metrix` memory of size `Entry grid[3][3]` will be allocated.
Function `emptyMatrix` is returning an object of type `Matrix` and the object will be returned by value just like any other object.

Comment: That's just wrong, there is not memory allocation involved here. Maybe you meant "created"?

Comment: @Frank; Memory will be allocated but at compile time (not dynamic memory allocation).

Comment: But `Matrix` is treated as a single continuous block of memory. There is a single allocation for the root struct, unless you count figuring out the size of `Matrix` as 'allocation', but that's a stretch IMO.

Comment: @Frank; For every object compiler allocates memory. Note that I am talking about the memory allocation at compile time not at the run time.